# Python Alternative to .split() for generator/list

Tags: python

How can I add a new line after each object in my generator or list?  I tried .join('\n') and that didn't work.  Trying to split a newline won't work because that's not an attribute of the generator or list datatype.

My try with a generator = false to use a list using join:

```
a = conn.extend.standard.paged_search('cn = All.DL Div Controllers - National Group, ou = Distribution Lists, ou = Exchange, dc=google,dc=corpad,dc=net', '(objectClass=*)', attributes=['member'], generator=False)
b = map(str, a)         #Stringify each a from generator
b_str = '\n'.join(b) #Join the list of b with a newline
with open ('test.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(b_str) #Write to file
```

My output looks like this `aaaa, aaaaa, aaaaaa,aaa,aaaaa,aaaaa`

I want my output to look like this:

```
aaaa,
aaaaa,
aaaaaa,
aaa,
aaaaa,
aaaaa,
```

Here is my attempt using .split(), but it obviously wont' work as .split() is not an attribute of a generator or list datatype.

```
#a= conn.extend.standard.paged_search('cn = All.DL Div Controllers - National Group, ou = Distribution Lists, ou = Exchange, dc=google,dc=corpad,dc=net', '(objectClass=*)', attributes=['member'])
#for b in a.split('\n'):
#    with open ('test.txt', 'w') as file:
#        file.write (str(a))
```

The above is just an example the true output in the console including each print statement is the following:

Code:

```
national = conn.extend.standard.paged_search('cn = All.DL Div Controllers - National Group, ou = Distribution Lists, ou = Exchange, dc=google,dc=corpad,dc=net', '(objectClass=*)', attributes=['member'], generator=False)
print(national)
```

Output:

```
[{'raw_dn': b'CN=All.DL Div Controllers - National Group,OU=Distribution Lists,OU=Exchange,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
     'dn': 'CN=All.DL Div Controllers - National Group,OU=Distribution Lists,OU=Exchange,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
     'raw_attributes': {'member': [b'CN=gji9847,OU=U02562,OU=02562,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                                   b'CN=exx8092,OU=U06032,OU=06032,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                                   b'CN=EWR8386,OU=U09373,OU=09373,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                                   b'CN=HXU9279,OU=U00704,OU=00704,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                                   b'CN=KVG6693,OU=U25692,OU=25692,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                                   b'CN=JCL6495,OU=U01246,OU=01246,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                                   b'CN=RNE9520,OU=U01673,OU=01673,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                                   b'CN=PCN5400,OU=U01673,OU=01673,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                                   b'CN=WPM9271,OU=U01673,OU=01673,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                                   b'CN=JKJ2421,OU=U01692,OU=01692,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net']},
     'attributes': {'member': ['CN=gji9847,OU=U02562,OU=02562,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               'CN=exx8092,OU=U06032,OU=06032,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               'CN=EWR8386,OU=U09373,OU=09373,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               'CN=HXU9279,OU=U00704,OU=00704,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               'CN=KVG6693,OU=U25692,OU=25692,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               'CN=JCL6495,OU=U01246,OU=01246,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               'CN=RNE9520,OU=U01673,OU=01673,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               'CN=PCN5400,OU=U01673,OU=01673,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               'CN=WPM9271,OU=U01673,OU=01673,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               'CN=JKJ2421,OU=U01692,OU=01692,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net']},
     'type': 'searchResEntry'}]
```

Code:

```
print (len(list(national)))
```

Output:

```
1
```

Code:

```
controllers = map(str, national)         #Stringify each controller from generator
print(controllers)
```

Output:

```
<map object at 0x000001BF3AF35080>
```

Code:

```
controllers_str = '\n'.join(controllers) #Join the list of controllers with a newline
print(controllers_str)
```

Output:

```
{'raw_dn': b'CN=All.DL Div Controllers - National Group,OU=Distribution Lists,OU=Exchange,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
     'dn': 'CN=All.DL Div Controllers - National Group,OU=Distribution Lists,OU=Exchange,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
     'raw_attributes': {'member': [b'CN=gji9847,OU=U02562,OU=02562,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                                   b'CN=exx8092,OU=U06032,OU=06032,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                                   b'CN=EWR8386,OU=U09373,OU=09373,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                                   b'CN=HXU9279,OU=U00704,OU=00704,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                                   b'CN=KVG6693,OU=U25692,OU=25692,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                                   b'CN=JCL6495,OU=U01246,OU=01246,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                                   b'CN=RNE9520,OU=U01673,OU=01673,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                                   b'CN=PCN5400,OU=U01673,OU=01673,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                                   b'CN=WPM9271,OU=U01673,OU=01673,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                                   b'CN=JKJ2421,OU=U01692,OU=01692,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net']},
     'attributes': {'member': ['CN=gji9847,OU=U02562,OU=02562,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               'CN=exx8092,OU=U06032,OU=06032,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               'CN=EWR8386,OU=U09373,OU=09373,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               'CN=HXU9279,OU=U00704,OU=00704,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               'CN=KVG6693,OU=U25692,OU=25692,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               'CN=JCL6495,OU=U01246,OU=01246,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               'CN=RNE9520,OU=U01673,OU=01673,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               'CN=PCN5400,OU=U01673,OU=01673,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               'CN=WPM9271,OU=U01673,OU=01673,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               'CN=JKJ2421,OU=U01692,OU=01692,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net']},
     'type': 'searchResEntry'}
```

Comment: @scharette python is clever enough to convert line endings automatically. OP, your code is writing `controllers_str`, not `b_str`. Is this intended?

Comment: After your edit, I doubt that what you have written isn't working. I see no reason why it shouldn't. Are you sure `len(list(b)) > 1`?

Comment: That's the issue my len(list) is only = to 1.

Comment: Wait, so your generator only produces a single element which looks like `'aaaa, aaaaa, aaaaaa,aaa,aaaaa,aaaaa'`?

Comment: Apparently, how can I get that to line break after each comma?  Or would I be better off reading that text file being produced and doing the editing there?  I'm new to all of this.

Comment: The generator is being created with the ldap3 library to connect to active directory, i'm not in control of how the output comes out of active directory.

Comment: The above is just an example of the code.  The single element looks like this, which is created with the ldap3 module.  {'raw_dn': b'CN=All.DL Div DSS Directors,OU=Distribution Lists,OU=Exchange,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net', 'dn': 'CN=All.DL Div DSS Directors,OU=Distribution Lists,OU=Exchange,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net', 'raw_attributes': {'member': [b'CN=clo7795,OU=U08732,OU=08732,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net', b'CN=KHU8294,OU=U08732,OU=08732,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net', b'CN=HDU8583,OU=U08732,OU=08732,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net', 'type': 'searchResEntry'}

Comment: the element isn't valid python. There is an unmatched `[`.

Comment: any suggestions on how I can clean it up to make the output easier to work with?

Comment: As a start you could paste the single element **as it prints out in the console** in your original question as an edit. I can't work with invalid python.

Comment: Thank you Mitchell.  I've added the code and output as it prints in the console as requested.

Comment: Also, the line break should occur after every DC=net', statement.

Comment: Ok thanks -- See my edit

Answer (score 1):

ok so national is a list of length 1. To get the object we care about, all you need to do is `national_dict = national[0]`. I called it this since `national_dict` is a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), not a string.

To print out a nicely formatted dictionary, one option is to pretty print

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(national_dict, width=100)  # width defaults to 79
```

which outputs

```
{'attributes': {'member': ['CN=gji9847,OU=U02562,OU=02562,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                           'CN=exx8092,OU=U06032,OU=06032,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                           'CN=EWR8386,OU=U09373,OU=09373,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                           'CN=HXU9279,OU=U00704,OU=00704,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                           'CN=KVG6693,OU=U25692,OU=25692,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                           'CN=JCL6495,OU=U01246,OU=01246,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                           'CN=RNE9520,OU=U01673,OU=01673,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                           'CN=PCN5400,OU=U01673,OU=01673,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                           'CN=WPM9271,OU=U01673,OU=01673,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                           'CN=JKJ2421,OU=U01692,OU=01692,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net']},
 'dn': 'CN=All.DL Div Controllers - National Group,OU=Distribution '
       'Lists,OU=Exchange,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
 'raw_attributes': {'member': [b'CN=gji9847,OU=U02562,OU=02562,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               b'CN=exx8092,OU=U06032,OU=06032,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               b'CN=EWR8386,OU=U09373,OU=09373,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               b'CN=HXU9279,OU=U00704,OU=00704,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               b'CN=KVG6693,OU=U25692,OU=25692,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               b'CN=JCL6495,OU=U01246,OU=01246,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               b'CN=RNE9520,OU=U01673,OU=01673,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               b'CN=PCN5400,OU=U01673,OU=01673,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               b'CN=WPM9271,OU=U01673,OU=01673,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net',
                               b'CN=JKJ2421,OU=U01692,OU=01692,DC=google,DC=corpad,DC=net']},
 'raw_dn': b'CN=All.DL Div Controllers - National Group,OU=Distribution Lists,OU=Exchange,DC=goog'
           b'le,DC=corpad,DC=net',
 'type': 'searchResEntry'}
```

Is this sort of what you're looking for?

---

In order to pretty print to a file

```
import pprint
formatted = pprint.pformat(national_dict, width=100)
with open(filename, 'w') as fw:
    fw.write(formatted)
```

Comment: You can also use `print(..., file=f)` and it will handle the newlines etc

Comment: It's been a while, I was out of my country all month disconnected.  This is sort of what I was looking for, but instead of printing, I want the text file being wrote to display like the pretty print.

Answer (score 1):

Can you replace each comma with ",\n"?
`b = str(a).replace(',',',\n')`

Comment: I think you're on to something.  I can replace every DC = net', with DC = net', \n.